# JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set not getting the response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

when i am going to convert the currency using xe currency converter api but not getting the response

The expected response should be like

> {"terms":"http://www.xe.com/legal/dfs.php","privacy":"http://www.xe.com/privacy.php","from":"USD","amount":1.0,"timestamp":"2016-03-18T06:22:00Z","to":[{"quotecurrency":"INR","mid":66.6094587811}]}

i am getting the below error in response:

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa879f70190 {Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo= –
>   {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= { URL: xecdapi.xe.com/v1/convert_from? } { status code: 404, headers { Connection = "keep-alive"; "Content-Length" = 9; "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"; } }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404), NSErrorFailingURLKey=xecdapi.xe.com/v1/convert_from?}}}

my code is:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonResponseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSMutableSet *jsonAcceptableContentTypes = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
[jsonAcceptableContentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = jsonAcceptableContentTypes;
manager.responseSerializer = jsonResponseSerializer;
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@“xxxxxxxxninternationalfze988134762" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User Name"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@“xxxxqngksq5nuqmmf7tjgcihak" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Password"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[params setObject:@"USD" forKey:@"from"];
[params setObject:@"INR" forKey:@"to"];
```

Comment: The JSON response which you are getting is not in correct JSON format. Thus, this error occurs.
The above JSON is correct.
Check the response you are getting from server.

Comment: Thats exactly what I said, the response is not in correct format. Convert the response in json string and check it in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Please send the response which you get from server

Comment: I think you can check by changing @"text/plain" to @"application/json"

Comment: @TapashMollick Please add whatever information you provided in the comments as an edit / update to your question.

Comment: @TapashMollick pass this thing in postman or any other tools and see what you get. One case is that you get fatal error from server

Comment: Thanks it's working now.